# When entering a string in the console. Only the first word is then printed

Tags: c++, string

So I create a string:

```
 string randomstring;
```

Then I enter something in the console of what it should contain

> "A broken string"

And now when I type:

```
  cout << randomstring << endl;
```

The output reads

> A

Why doesn't it prints the whole string ?

Comment: It would help if you showed how you're getting the input. We can assume you're doing `std::cin >> randomstring;` but we shouldn't have to...

Comment: `cin >> randomstring` ignores leading whitespace, then reads up to the next whitespace it encounters.  Thus would read only `A` the first time, then `broken` the next time, then `string` the next time, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::getline()` when you take a string input from the user.

```
std::string str;
std::getline(std::cin, str);
std::cout << str << std::endl;
```